# C++ Mouse Reading very unreactive

Tags: c++, dll, mouse

Straight to the point, I'm developing a dll which simply reads the mouse coords and converts them into rotation and then into some coordinates, for an fps style camera.

The problem is that the mouse reader is very insensitive, if i move my mouse slowly it wont record anything, but if i move it very fast, it will record the changes.

Now the code:

main.cpp

```
#define DLL_EXPORT
#define BOOST_THREAD_USE_DLL

#include "DLL\Viewport.h"
#include "MouseReader.h"
#include <boost\thread\thread.hpp>
#include <assert.h>

using namespace std;

#define PHI 3.141592653589

MouseListenerObject MouseListener;
double clax, clay, claz;
double Altitude, Azimuth;

bool IsActive;

static void CalcCLA_XYZ();
void FPSThread();

boost::thread *fpsstylethread;

void ViewportManagerObject::StartFPSStyle()
{
    IsActive = true;
    fpsstylethread = new boost::thread(&FPSThread);

    assert(fpsstylethread->joinable());
}

void ViewportManagerObject::StopFPSStyle()
{
    IsActive = false;
    fpsstylethread->detach();
}

void FPSThread()
{
    while(IsActive == true)
    {
        CalcCLA_XYZ();
    }
}

vector<double> ViewportManagerObject::ReturnCLA_XYZ()
{
    vector<double> returnval;
    returnval.insert(returnval.begin(), clax);
    returnval.insert(returnval.begin()+1, clay);
    returnval.insert(returnval.begin()+2, claz);

    return returnval;
}

void CalcCLA_XYZ()
{
    MouseListener.ReadMouse();

    vector<int> MouseCoordChange = MouseListener.Change;

    bool hasoperated = false;
    if (Azimuth + (MouseCoordChange[0] / 20) > 360)
    {
        Azimuth = (Azimuth + (MouseCoordChange[0] / 20)) - 360;
        hasoperated = true;
    }

    if (Azimuth + (MouseCoordChange[0] / 20) < 0)
    {
        Azimuth = (Azimuth + (MouseCoordChange[0] / 20)) + 360;
        hasoperated = true;
    }

    if (hasoperated == false)
    {
        Azimuth += (MouseCoordChange[0] / 20);
    }

    if (!((Altitude - (MouseCoordChange[1] / 20)) > 160) && !((Altitude - (MouseCoordChange[1] / 20)) < 5))
    {
        Altitude -= (MouseCoordChange[1] / 20);
    }

    clax = 1 * cos((Altitude/360)*(2*PHI)) * cos((Azimuth/360)*(2*PHI));
    clay = 1 * sin((Altitude/360)*(2*PHI));
    claz = 1 * cos((Altitude/360)*(2*PHI)) * sin((Azimuth/360)*(2*PHI));
}
```

MouseReader.h

```
#ifndef MR_H
#define MR_H

#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class MouseListenerObject
{
    int newposx;
    int newposy;

    int oldposx;
    int oldposy;

    bool first;

public: vector<int> Change;

public: MouseListenerObject()
    {
        first = true;
    }

public: void ReadMouse()
    {
        POINT MousePoint;
        GetCursorPos(&MousePoint);

        if (first != false)
        {
            oldposx = MousePoint.x;
            oldposy = MousePoint.y;

            first = false;

            vector<int> nullvector;
            nullvector.insert(nullvector.begin(), 0);
            nullvector.insert(nullvector.begin() + 1, 0);
            Change = nullvector;

            return;
        }

        oldposx = newposx; // Lets make the previous values old...
        oldposy = newposy;

        newposx = MousePoint.x; // Update the new ones.
        newposy = MousePoint.y;

        int changex, changey; // Calc. the change and put it in a vector.

        changex = newposx - oldposx;
        changey = newposy - oldposy;

        vector<int> returnval;
        returnval.insert(returnval.begin(), changex);
        returnval.insert(returnval.begin() + 1, changey);

        Change = returnval;
    }
};

#endif
```

Viewport.h

```
#ifndef CVP_H
#define CVP_H

#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#if defined DLL_EXPORT
    #define DECLDIR __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DECLDIR __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class ViewportManagerObject
{
    public:DECLDIR void StartFPSStyle();

    public:DECLDIR void StopFPSStyle();

    public:DECLDIR vector<double> ReturnCLA_XYZ();
};

#endif
```

I'm so sorry that the post isn't more informative, but i was short on time.

Please ask me if anything guys.

Thank You.

Comment: GetCursorPos is a windows.h function which return a POINT, x and y.

Comment: *Straight to the point* More like *I just met you, and this is crazy /  But here's my code: debug it for me, mkay?*

Comment: The Legitimacy of a question should be in terms of how useful it can be to others. And i believe there will be other users looking for an answer to a similar question. Nevertheless now since the issue is resolved - I think it would be appropriate to trim away the irrelevant portion of the code in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `CalcCLA_XYZ()` you are dividing `MouseCoordChange` by 20 this is the problem I think. First replace all `20` with `MOUSE_SENSITIVITY` and `# define` it as a lesser number. See how it responds beginning from `1`; also you may want to cast it to double or float to make it a floating point division to prevent truncation of the fractional part because right now `MouseCoordChange[0]/20` is an integer division. You may also define `MOUSE_SENSITIVITY` as `1.0` to make it a float division.